# Redux: combine the `reducres` for not flat state with avoiding to create big count of reducers

Tags: javascript, redux

I learn Redux and try to create and combine the *reducers* for simple model for the shools, classes, and students. I want to implement such structure of my *state*:

```
const model = {
  schools:[
    { id: "91cb54b3-1289-4520-abe1-d8826d39fce3",
      name: "School #25", address: "Green str. 12",
      classes: [
        { id: "336ff233-746f-441b-84c7-0e6c275a7e24", name: "1A",
          students: [
            { id: "475dd06e-a52d-4d90-aa07-46eab7c029a7", name: "Ivan Ivanov",
              age: 7, phones: ["+7-123-456-78-90"] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I understand I can create reducer for each propery, but it will be very hard if model will be big. Therefore I would like to minimize the count of reducers. I thought the solution will be simple, but I faced with problem for my reducers combining...

Also, I see the addition problem... For example, for my current implementation how can I add the `class` instance in the second school? It means I am to point the school id... But if I need to add student's phone then I need to point the ids of each parrent for getting necessary student (i.e. id of school, class, and student)... It is possible my current implementation is wrong... I am not sure already...

I'm confused. :((( I understand how to use `combineReducers` for simple flat model, but I haven't idea how to do it for more complex cases...

This is my "sandbox" where I learn Redux and try to use `combineReducers` for my "business model":

```
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {uuidv4} from "uuid/v4"; // yarn add uuid

const createId = uuidv4; // creates new GUID
const deepClone = object => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));

/**
I will use simple model: the shools, classes, and students:

const model = {
  schools:[
    { id: "91cb54b3-1289-4520-abe1-d8826d39fce3",
      name: "School #25", address: "Green str. 12",
      classes: [
        { id: "336ff233-746f-441b-84c7-0e6c275a7e24", name: "1A",
          students: [
            { id: "475dd06e-a52d-4d90-aa07-46eab7c029a7", name: "Ivan Ivanov",
              age: 7, phones: ["+7-123-456-78-90"] }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
*/

// ================= Business model ====================
function createSchool(name = "", address = "", classes = []){
  return { id: createId(), name, address, classes };
}

function createClass(name = "", students = []){
  return { id: createId(), name, students };
}

function createStudent(name = "", age = 0, phones = []){
  return { id: createId(), name, age, phones };
}

function createPhone(phone = ""){
  return { id: createId(), phone };
}
// ================= end of Business model =============

const ACTION_KEYS = { // It is used by Action model
  CREATE_SCHOOL: "CREATE_SCHOOL",
  UPDATE_SCHOOL: "UPDATE_SCHOOL",
  DELETE_SCHOOL: "DELETE_SCHOOL",

  CREATE_CLASS: "CREATE_CLASS",
  UPDATE_CLASS: "UPDATE_CLASS",
  DELETE_CLASS: "DELETE_CLASS",

  CREATE_STUDENT: "CREATE_STUDENT",
  UPDATE_STUDENT: "UPDATE_STUDENT",
  DELETE_STUDENT: "DELETE_STUDENT",

  CREATE_PHONE: "CREATE_PHONE",
  UPDATE_PHONE: "UPDATE_PHONE",
  DELETE_PHONE: "DELETE_PHONE",
}

// ==================== Action model ======================

// School actions:

function create_createShoolAction(value = createSchool()){
  // use createSchool() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_SCHOOL, value };
}

function create_updateShoolAction(value){
  // use createSchool() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_SCHOOL, value };
}

function create_deleteShoolAction(id){
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_SCHOOL, id };
}

// Class actions:

function create_createClassAction(value = createClass()){
  // use createClass() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_CLASS, value };
}

function create_updateClassAction(value){
  // use createClass() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_CLASS, value };
}

function create_deleteClassAction(id){
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_CLASS, id };
}

// Student actions:

function create_createStudentAction(value = createStudent()){
  // use createStudent() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_STUDENT, value };
}

function create_updateStudentAction(value){
  // use createStudent() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_STUDENT, value };
}

function create_deleteStudentAction(id){
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_STUDENT, id };
}

// Phone actions:

function create_createPhoneAction(value = createPhone()){
  // use createPhone() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_PHONE, value };
}

function create_updatePhoneAction(value){
  // use createPhone() function for 'value' initializing
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_PHONE, value };
}

function create_deletePhoneAction(id){
  return {type: ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_PHONE, id };
}
// ==================== end of Action model ===============

// ========================= Reducers =====================

// This function contains common implementation for all my reducers (I'm lazy).
function reducer(state = [], action, action_keys){
  switch(action.type){
    switch action_keys[0]: { // create new item
      return [...deepClone(state), ...deepClone(action.value)];
      break;
    }
    switch action_keys[1]: { // update existing item
      const index = state.findIndex(n => n.id === action.value.id);
      if(index < 0) return state;
      const clonedState = [...deepClone(state)];
      return [...clonedState.slice(0, index), ...deepClone(action.value),
        ...clonedState.slice(index + 1)];
      break;
    }
    switch action_keys[2]: { // delete existing item
      const index = state.findIndex(n => n.id === action.id);
      if(index < 0) return state;
      const clonedState = [...deepClone(state)];
      return [...clonedState.slice(0, index), ...clonedState.slice(index + 1)];
      break;
    }
    default: { // otherwise return original
      return state;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function schoolReducer(state = [], action){
  return reducer(state, action, [
    ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_SCHOOL,
    ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_SCHOOL,
    ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_SCHOOL
  ]);
}

function classReducer(state = [], action){
  return reducer(state, action, [
    ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_CLASS,
    ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_CLASS,
    ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_CLASS
  ]);
}

function studentReducer(state = [], action){
  return reducer(state, action, [
    ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_STUDENT,
    ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_STUDENT,
    ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_STUDENT
  ]);
}

function phoneReducer(state = [], action){
  return reducer(state, action, [
    ACTION_KEYS.CREATE_PHONE,
    ACTION_KEYS.UPDATE_PHONE,
    ACTION_KEYS.DELETE_PHONE
  ]);
}

// The "top-level" combined reducer
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  schools: schoolReducer
  // Oops... How to build the hierarchy of the remaining reducers (classReducer,
  // studentReducer, and phoneReducer)?
});
// =============== end of Reducers =====================

const store = createStore(combinedReducer);

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log("subscribe:",
  store.getState()));

// Now to work with the store...

store.dispatch(create_createShoolAction(createShool("Shool #5", "Green str. 7")));
store.dispatch(create_createShoolAction(createShool("Shool #12", "Read str. 15")));
store.dispatch(create_createShoolAction(createShool("Shool #501", "Wall str. 123")));

// Now, how can I add a new class into the "Shool #12" school?
// store.dispatch(???);
```

How properly to create and combine the reducers for such not flat state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand I can create reducer for each propery, but it will be
>   very hard if model will be big.

I don't understand that point of yours, since you already experience how bad it is to update a nested structure: you need to travel deep down, search for field and handle updates carefully to not break existing data. Worse is, with your nested structure, cost for rendering React components will be high since updating a phone number will required you to deep clone almost everything.

Normally my image of redux state is a client-side sql database, where each models (e.g. school, class, student) should be stored in separated tables; child should contain parent id and parent can contain child ids as array for two-way searching.

The good way is to break your reducer into separated reducers for every model, and use some middlewares like redux-thunk or redux-saga to handle updating in related models when you add - delete anything.

If you are too lazy to break things down, then 1 reducer is still fine; but you need to normalize the data for better data manipulation:

```
const initialState = {
  schools: {},
  classes: {},
  students: {}
}

function reducer(state = initialState, actions, action_keys) {
  ...
}
```

So your data sample can look like this:

```
{
  schools: {
    "91cb54b3-1289-4520-abe1-d8826d39fce3": {
      id: "91cb54b3-1289-4520-abe1-d8826d39fce3",
      name: "School #25",
      address: "Green str. 12",
      classes: [
        "336ff233-746f-441b-84c7-0e6c275a7e24"
      ]
    }
  },
  classes: {
    "336ff233-746f-441b-84c7-0e6c275a7e24": {
      id: "336ff233-746f-441b-84c7-0e6c275a7e24",
      schoolId: "91cb54b3-1289-4520-abe1-d8826d39fce3",
      name: "1A",
      students: [
        "475dd06e-a52d-4d90-aa07-46eab7c029a7"
      ]
    }
  },
  students: {
    "475dd06e-a52d-4d90-aa07-46eab7c029a7": {
      id: "475dd06e-a52d-4d90-aa07-46eab7c029a7",
      classId: "336ff233-746f-441b-84c7-0e6c275a7e24"
      name: "Ivan Ivanov",
      age: 7,
      phones: ["+7-123-456-78-90"]
    }
  }
}
```

How you implement actions to handle updating data is your own problem, but with the above structure, it should be easier for you to solve.